# IllegalFlowLogicException when calling CordaRPCOps.startFlow

Tags: corda

In a CorDapp, I defined the following flow:

```
@InitiatingFlow
@StartableByRPC
class EchoFlow(private val msg: String): FlowLogic<String>() {
    override fun call(): String {
        return msg
    }
}
```

I then deployed the CorDapp to a node and tried to run it as follows:

```
val result = proxy.startFlow { EchoFlow("msg") }.returnValue.getOrThrow()
```

However, I received the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" net.corda.core.flows.IllegalFlowLogicException: 
FlowLogicRef cannot be constructed for FlowLogic of type com.template.EchoFlow due to missing constructor for arguments: []
```

How should I invoke a flow using `CordaRPCOps.startFlow`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CordaRPCOps.startFlow` is used by passing a flow constructor, following by a vararg of arguments to the flow. So in Kotlin, you'd invoke the flow by running:

```
val result = proxy.startFlow(::EchoFlow, "msg").returnValue.getOrThrow()
```

Where `::ClassName` is the Kotlin syntax for getting a reference to the flow's constructor.

Alternatively, you could use `CordaRPCOps.startFlowDynamic`. This method takes a flow instance instead, as follows:

```
val result = proxy.startFlowDynamic(EchoFlow("msg")).returnValue.getOrThrow()
```